# Usage of Redux Form Fields component inside a FieldArray component

Tags: redux-form

I have a `Fields` component that I am trying to use sometimes by itself and sometimes from inside a `FieldArray` component. I have added a snippet below with a simplified model.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Fields, FieldArray, reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

const reducers = {
  form: formReducer
};

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);

const store = createStore(reducer);

const renderSharedComponent = (fields) => {
  console.log(fields);
  return (<div>Shared Component</div>);
};

const renderHashes = ({ fields }) => (
  <div>
    {
      fields.map((field) => (
        <Fields
          key={ field }
          names={ [`${field}.value`, `${field}.valueIsRegex`] }
          component={ renderSharedComponent }
        />
      ))
    }
  </div>
);

const ReactComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <FieldArray
      name="hashes"
      component={ renderHashes }
    />
    <Fields
      names={ ['value', 'valueIsRegex'] }
      component={ renderSharedComponent }
    />
  </div>
);

const ReduxForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'default',
  initialValues: {
    hashes: [{}]
  }
})(ReactComponent);

ReactDOM.render((
  <div>
    <Provider store={ store }>
      <ReduxForm />
    </Provider>
  </div>
), document.getElementById('content'));
```

When I use the `Fields` component by itself, the `fields` argument from inside `renderSharedComponent` has the following form:

```
{
  value: { input: {...}, meta: {...} },
  valueIsRegex: { input: {...}, meta: {...} },
  names: [ 'value' , 'valueIsRegex' ]
}
```

When I use the `Fields` component inside a `FieldArray` component, the `fields` argument from inside `renderSharedComponent` has the following form:

```
{
  hashes: [
      {
        value: { input: {...}, meta: {...} },
        valueIsRegex: { input: {...}, meta: {...} }
      }
  ],
  names: [ 'hashes[0].value' , 'hashes[0].valueIsRegex' ]
}
```

If I will be using the `Fields` component inside a `FieldArray` component with a different name (let's say `paths`) the names property will change accordingly (eg. `names: [ 'paths[0].value' , 'paths[0].valueIsRegex' ]`).

I am trying to get the `value` and `valueIsRegex` objects in a generic way that will support any of the cases I presented above.

Right now I have created a function where I use a RegEx to determine the fields. But I was wondering if anyone knows a better way to do this (maybe there is a Redux Form util that maybe I missed when reading the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

having the same problem. It may be that the idiomatic way is to use the `formValueSelector` [function](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/docs/api/FormValueSelector.md/). But that way its a bit more boilerplate, as you have to pass the selector (as far as I understood it) all the way down through the form.
Personally I did the regexp-based function as well. Here it is:

````js
/**
 * Converts path expression string to array
 * @param {string} pathExpr path string like "bindings[0][2].labels[0].title"
 * @param {Array<string|int>} array path like ['bindings', 0, 2, 'labels', 0, 'title']
 */
function breakPath(pathExpr) {
    return pathExpr
        .split(/\]\.|\]\[|\[|\]|\./)
        .filter(x => x.length > 0)
        .map(x => isNaN(parseInt(x)) ? x : parseInt(x));
}

/**
 * Executes path expression on the object
 * @param {string} pathExpr – path string like "bindings[0][2].labels[0].title"
 * @param {Object|Array} obj - object or array value
 * @return {mixed} a value lying in expression path
 * @example 
 * ```
 * execPath('books[0].title', {books: [{title: 'foo'}]})
 * // yields
 * 'foo' 
 * ```
 */
function execPath(pathExpr, obj) {
    const path = breakPath(pathExpr);
    if (path.length < 1) {
        return obj;
    }
    return path.reduce(function(obj, pathPart) {
        return obj[pathPart];
    }, obj);
}

/**
 * A generic GroupLabelField that relies on valueBasePath
 */
const GroupLabelField = (props) => {
    const groupData = execPath(props.valueBasePath, props);
    return (
        <div className={`label__content label__content_icon_${groupData.objectType.input.value}`}>
            <span className="label__remove"
                  onClick={(e) => { props.handleRemove(); e.stopPropagation(); }}
            >
                <i className="material-icons material-icons_12 material-icons_top">&#xE5CD;</i>
            </span>
            <span className="label__text">{groupData.title.input.value}</span>
        </div>
    );
};
````

Answer (score 1):

redux-form has a hidden utility function which is useful here, but I don't know if you can rely on it's availability in future versions:

```
import structure from "redux-form/lib/structure/plain";

function RenderRow({ names, ...props }) {
  const fields = {};
  names.forEach(n => (fields[n] = structure.getIn(props, n)));
}
```

See also [this github issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2024)